# intellij ide android building error

Tags: java, android, macos, intellij-idea, ide

I just install intellij idea 13 ce on my mac and I open a new android project I install everything adb works fine but I have this error.

I use maverick 10.9.4

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: posix_spawn is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform.
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:105)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:94)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<clinit>(UNIXProcess.java:92)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isRoot0(PlatformDependent.java:430)
```